# Why declared variables in Javascript are non-configurable in the current scope?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hoisting

I have created a variable **x** with the keyword **var** but when I do the following:

```
var x = 10;
delete x;
```

It returns **false**. basically, I don't want to delete the x variable but my question is that why javascript does not allow to configure the variables declared in the current scope context. This is also mentioned in [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description), but the question is **why**?

Comment: The `delete` operator was never meant to do anything with regards to scoped variables - it only makes sense in the context of deleting a property from an object, which is quite a different concept

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise every `x` might or might not throw an error or might suddenly refer to another variable:

```
  let x = 2;
  {
     let x = 3;
     if(Math.random() > 0.5) delete x;
     console.log(x); // ?!
  }
```

That makes code conpletely error prone and unpredictable and makes it impossible to optimize, every line might suddenly become a syntax error, and thats why it is not possible to delete variables that way.

However there is another way to get this behaviour by adding an object as scope which you can mutate, and thats the reason why no one uses the `with` statement:

```
  const scope = { b: 2 };
  with(scope) {
    console.log(b); // 2
    delete scope.b;
    console.log(b); // reference error
  }
```

Comment: Not the right answer. Ok the answer above is for the variable declared with keyword **var**, ok suppose I declared without the keyword **var**, then why it is able to be deleted even it is in the use in later code? Then ?

Comment: @purpleBytes because `window` was a bad design decision, just as `with` ...

Comment: There is nothing about the **window** object.

Comment: @purpleBytes wrong. `a = 1; delete window.a; console.log(a);`

Comment: variables declared with var in global scope or without var are attached to the **window** object. There is nothing to say about the **window** object.

Comment: the question is why variables with **var** is not able to configure in the scope where it is declared?

Comment: @purpleBytes yup and that what the answer above answers. You cannot delete it because the inventors of JS decided that it would be a very bad idea.

Comment: deleting any default property is a bad idea, deleting a variable that is declared is not a bad idea. A programmer should have the freedom to do anything on those statements that he created. So, your answer is not right. Anyways thank you so much.

Comment: @purpleBytes if you really need that use the `with` statement. JS allows you to do such things, it just restricts those very dynamic things to certain keywords (`with`, `eval` ...) so that you can avoid them in real code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a variable if you declared it (with var x;) at the time of first use.
However, if your variable x first appeared in the script without a declaration,

you can delete the variable if you didn't use var keyword.

[image]

you can get more information from this resource 
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/deleteavariable.htm

Comment: Your answer context is the same as the question, **why** You cannot delete a variable if you declared it (with var x;) at the time of first use ?