# Why are implicit variables configurable, while explicit variables and function declarations are not?

Tags: javascript

Why are implicit variables configurable, while explicit variables and function declarations are not?

```js
foo = ''
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'foo')) // configurable: true

var bar = ''
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'bar')) // configurable: false
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807557/why-declared-variables-in-javascript-are-non-configurable-in-the-current-scope).

Comment: Implicitly created variables are not declared.

Comment: This sounds like a restatement of the question?

Comment: For explanation [`MDN ref`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: It's a good explanation, actually. `foo` is a property of `window` so you can manipulate it as if it's...well, a normal property. However `bar` is a *declared variable* that also happens to be a property of `window`. So, configuring it will lead to strange behaviour - what does it mean to make a `var` non-writeable, is it now a constant? But wait, it *cannot* be, since it's a `var` variable, so it will be inconsistent if you cannot write to it.

Comment: Well, I removed "because", before the edit you asked about "declared implicit variables" which don't exist. That is an explanation also, though.

Comment: Having dug into the specification, there is no such thing as an implicitly created variable in JavaScript. `foo = 'bar'` is equivalent to `globalThis.foo = 'bar'.` So it is insufficient to say "implicitly created variables are not declared": implicitly created variables do not exist in the language.

Comment: @52d6c6af That's still not the entire truth, _implicit globals_ partially behave like variables (you can refer them with the property name only, no need for the reference to the object), no other object implements that behavior.

Comment: The reason this works (of course) is that the global object actually forms part of the global execution context's lexical environment. Would you say that `Number` is a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables get put into the current scope, or Lexical Environment (an internal map of variable names to the values they contain) only when the variables are *declared* - that is, with `const`, `let`, or `var`.

If this happens, those variables are not deletable; they can't be removed from a scope once declared. On the top level, global variables with `var` are assigned to the global object. The property is not removeable from the global object because the identifier is not deletable from the global scope - so, it's not configurable.

When you don't declare a variable, you assign to a property of the global object in sloppy mode, but you *don't* create an identifier for the global lexical environment. It's just a property of the global object, not a standalone variable name, so it's deletable (and thus configurable).

Comment: `var` declarations seem to be placed in the `VariableEnvironment` which is subtly distinct from the `LexicalEnvironment`, I think. Is the creation of the property on the `globalThis` part of the ECMAScript spec, or a W3C standard behavior - I'm looking for it in the spec.

Comment: @52d6c6af it's part of ES. Since version 1, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @52d6c6af See [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation): `For each String vn in declaredVarNames, in list order, do: `Perform ? envRec.CreateGlobalVarBinding(vn, false)` where that second argument determines whether the property is configurable or not.

Comment: Global bindings appear to be positioned directly on the global object, which itself is positioned as a "base" (presumably as in inheritance) of the global environment. So the global object is itself part of the global lexical environment. This suggests to me that both implicit and explicit variable declarations end up in the same place, but I haven't found the bit about implicit variables yet. Paragraph 2 [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-global-environment-records).

Comment: The only instance of `CreateGlobalVarBinding(F, true)` I can find is 7.a.i.i [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-web-compat-evaldeclarationinstantiation).

Comment: OK, so when you declare a `var` in the global ctxt, `CreateGlobalVarBinding ` is run, which, in addition to adding a property to t global object (which is actually a base of the global environment), adds an entry in a `[[VarNames]]` list of the global Env Record. When you fail to use `var` in sloppy mode, another code path is used, which results in the creation of a property (configurable by default), but not the addition of an entry in `[[VarNames]]`. So in sloppy mode `foo = 'bar'` is equivalent to `globalThis.foo = 'bar'`, and not `var foo = 'bar'`, even in the global context. Or something.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an implicit variable declaration in JavaScript.

In non-strict mode, if `foo` has not been declared, and regardless of whether we are in the global context, then:

`foo = 'bar'`

is equivalent to:

`globalThis.foo = bar`

This follows the normal JavaScript behavior of adding a new property to an object. The resulting property is configurable by default.

Whereas a variable declaration in the global context, like so:

`var foo = 'bar'`

...follows a different [logical process](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation) (`GlobalDeclarationInstantiation`), part of which involves the addition of the identifier to a `[[VarNames]]` internal slot (in [`CreateGlobalVarBinding`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-createglobalvarbinding)), **which is peculiar to the the *global* environment record**. Its specific purpose appears to be to permit the distinguishing between properties on the global object intended to be properties, and properties on the global object intended to be variables. As part of this process `CreateGlobalVarBinding` is invoked with `false` as the second argument, meaning the resulting property on the global object is non-configurable.

So although, in the global context, both `foo = 'bar'` and `var foo = 'bar'` result in a property on the global object, one is an ordinary property and the other is an ordinary-property-with-special-metadata-and-handling-logic.